# How to quickly get inside of this magic wand tool border selection - complex image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop

Original image : http://orig10.deviantart.net/cf51/f/2013/234/c/1/_8__uscail_by_el_dark_core-d6jbjv0.png

[image]

I need to get inside of this white border selection how to do it?

Here the selection

http://orig10.deviantart.net/ef62/f/2015/174/6/4/inside_of_here_by_monstermmorpg-d8yhv3e.png

[image]

Comment: I downvoted your question for the lack of effort shown and that you asked the same question on several sites none-of-which has shown what you've tried or implementation.  We are not a tutorial board and I would imagine a regular SO member based on your profile should know that. Reference: [Why your question was downvoted.](//meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/why-was-my-question-downvoted-and-or-closed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Select white with **Magic Wand**
- Enter **Quick Mask** mode by tapping the <kbd>Q</kbd> key
- Select internal area by clicking once with the **Magic Wand Tool**
- Fill with White.
- Choose `Select > Inverse` from the menu
- Fill with black
- Exit **Quick Mask** Mode by tapping the <kbd>Q</kbd> key again
- Add a new **Layer Mask** by clicking the icon at the bottom of the **Layer Panel**

[image]

- Done
- Add additional layers as needed.

This method would also remove any outline which falls outside the white halo. So if there were a black line, then a white line, then the image, this method would work well to remove any double or triple outline should it exist.

Often modifying a selection created by the Magic Wand Tool can be spotty - meaning it doesn't always contract/expand how you think it will. Using quick mask mode allows you to quickly alter selections based on solid areas rather than the actual image pixels. Then using layers masks keeps all the work **non-destructive** so if you ever do need to go backwards, the image data is still there.

Comment: ty for answer however i updated my question with real example. previous one was not appropriate for my question i see based on answers

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG this answer works exactly the same, even for your new images.

Comment: how do i fill with white? reproducing your stages atm ty

Comment: It should work the same... [SEE HERE](http://i.stack.imgur.com/H0Opw.jpg) The new image only makes selecting the white halo a bit more difficult, but once that's done the steps I've outlined work the same.

Comment: ok it is not working as your gif . 1: i choose border. 2: i click Q. 3: i select inside: 4: i press shift f5 and (contents white, blending normal, opacity 100%) however when i add new layer with icon right bottom i dont get such effect as yours

Comment: ok i think i am gonna do it. after add layer mask what do i do ty for answers

Comment: **New Layer Mask icon** not new Layer.

Comment: If this works and answered your question, just click the little check mark you see on the left at the top of the answer, below the voting buttons. That's all. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: no no after add layer mask i have this image now what do i do? http://orig15.deviantart.net/a661/f/2015/175/5/7/now_do_what_by_monstermmorpg-d8yjhxh.png

Comment: Just invert the mask. With the mask thumbnail highlighted in the layers panel, choose `Image > Adjustments > Invert`. That's all. You did it right, just need to invert the mask.

Comment: ty i solved it marked as answer. because of extremely simplistic missing feature (either single side reverse selection or inner selection) now have to do a lot of more steps :(

Comment: The more you do it, the faster it gets and it'll make more sense. These are just basic steps. I'm sure you'll adjust a bit as you do it a few times.

Comment: 1 more unrelated question. when i click ctrl S for save, can i select by default png image instead of psd file? for example after i have done with this process it brings save as psd instead of png

Comment: If this is for the web, you should use `File > Export` or File > Save for Web` to save the PNG. The PSD file keeps your layers and mask in tact. If you *never* want to change the image again, you can right-click the layer mask and choose `Apply Layer Mask`. That should save as just a PNG if you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can just set the tolerance of the magic want tool to 100 as shown below, then click on the background, which is the green area and delete it, then select the white border and delete that.

[image: Tolerance]

[image: Select background]

[image: Select white border]

[image: Result]

Comment: yes i can do that however it is not the solution i am looking for. this software is one of the most complex software on the world and i am looking extremely simple function. single sided inverse or extract inside of selection. isn't this possible?=

Comment: As far as I know, that isn't possible.

Comment: ty for answer do you know any other image software that can does this extremely simple basic functionality?

Comment: Not at all. Sorry I couldn't help with what you were looking for.

Comment: ty for answer however i updated my question with real example. previous one was not appropriate for my question i see based on answers

Answer (score 2):

You can simply select your image as you did, then go in the "select" menu, and then "modify".

Then you'll see the option to "expand" or "contract" your selection. There you can select the number of pixels you want to expand or contract your selection with.

[image: contract pixel selection Adobe Photoshop]

[image: selection with wand tool]

I found it gave better result if I deleted the background and white border. Then I selected the background, did a "select" then "inverse" and then a "modify/contract."

Edited: The wand tool is not the best way to select elements but it can work as a shortcut sometimes and the result doesn't seem so bad on a graphic like the sample you provided.

The best way to isolate an element and make a precise selection of your image is by using a layer mask with the help of brushes or the path tool. But since you want something quick, it might not work for this project ([How to add a layer mask](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-Layer-Mask-in-Photoshop).)

Comment: Upvoted for the bulk of this but don't agree with your last sentence at all. You don't select with a Layer Mask, they can be created with brushes, channels, marquees, etc.. so not even sure what you mean by the sentence.

Comment: I should have specified "the best way to isolate an element and make a precise selection of your image is by using a layer mask with the help of brushes or the path tool".

Comment: ty for answer however i updated my question with real example. previous one was not appropriate for my question i see based on answers

Comment: @Ryan updated my question as previous example was not appropriate example i see from answers. now more real example