# How to get inside a part of a selection (border) of an image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing, crop

I had this question previously, but it is not working anymore with Photoshop 2022: [How to quickly get inside of this magic wand tool border selection - complex image](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55494/how-to-quickly-get-inside-of-this-magic-wand-tool-border-selection-complex-ima)

I don't know why.

So here a new question.

Here is an example image:

[image]

I select its white border like this with magic wand:

[image]

Now how do I get inside of this selection (check the image above)? The selection is continuous.

Comment: Hi. What isn't working?  Not sure I understand what you are asking TBH. You can do *Select > Modify > Contract* to bring in a selection by a set number of pixels. Does that work for you?

Comment: Or `Select > Inverse`? Though I have to say I would likely either try to user Curves or Levels to increase the contrast between the background before using the magic wand... Or forget the magic wand and use the pen tool to "draw" the selection. Often with pictures like this one it gets you the cleaner edge... That or brush + a mask. Though tracing the outline with these methods takes more time.

Answer (score 1):

I've read the answer you refer to and tried the method on this particular image.

The problem in this case is that the white contour is broken by the two eyelashes in the right side.

If you click the white contour with Magic Wand Tool, you won't select the part between the two eyelashes. You can <kbd>Shift</kbd> + left click the missing part to add it to the selection, but the selection will still have a hole in it.

[image]

So when you enter Quick Mask Mode and try to click the inner area, it doesn't work because it's connected to the outer area.

[image]

A solution could be to use the Brush Tool to paint in the part missing from the selection with white.

[image]

Now the inner area is separated from the outer area and you can continue with the method described in the other answer.

[image]

You might want to add the two eyelashes to the selection afterwards, so you don't just cut them off. This could also be done in Quick Mask Mode with a white brush.

[image]

You probably need to put a little more effort into it than I did here.